# How can we secure IssuerSecret in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Just learning azure and i've noticed most of the samples have namespace, issuer and issuersecret in plain text inside the .cscfg or the web.config files.  This seems like a bad idea.  What is the best way to handle this so that is it not in plain text? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your web application needs to access them somehow anyway. So even if you encrypted them, you would still leave around an encryption key to unlock them.

Your .cscfg and .config files are securely protected on Azure. If your server is hacked, it doesn't really matter if you encrypted them or not, if you application has to use it and someone has access to your server, they can find out as much, if not more than your application and all the information your application is using.

The only secure way of storing something would be non-reverisble encryption. However you need the actual value, so it doesn't apply here. It would be more useful in storage of password's etc.